# Задача: Написать интерфейс для пульта от кондиционера

Tags: java

Прошу подсказать, не могу понять как как сделать реализацию интерфейса.

1.Нужно создать интерфейс, сделал:

public interface RemoteControlFromAirConditioner {

```
public boolean ON();
public boolean OFF();
public boolean IncreaseTemperature();
public boolean ReduceTemperature();
```

}

Далее, по условию нужно посмотреть возможности (вкл/выкл, добавить температуру/снизить)
Создать класс, которые реализует данный интерфейс:

Получилось так:

public class Conditioner implements RemoteControlFromAirConditioner {

```
public boolean ON() {

    return true;
}

public boolean OFF() {

    return false;
}

public boolean IncreaseTemperature() {

    return true;
}

public boolean ReduceTemperature() {

    return false;
}
```

}

Как добавить условия, к примеру что вкл - это включить, и что если вызвали метод ON, то снова его нельзя вызвать. Аналогично и с OFF

Далее, нельзя вызвать метод добавить/снизить температуру, пока конд. выключен

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте поле состояние кондиционера. и проверяйте его, например так

```
 public class Conditioner implements RemoteControlFromAirConditioner {

     private State curState;

     public boolean ON(){
          if(curState == State.WORKING){
              ...
          }
     }

     ...

     enum State{

         WORKING,
         ....

     }
 }
```